# HTML5 on mobile web browsers

Tags: html, mobile-website

I need your advice guys. I am developing a web browser application for mobile phones and it will be pure html5. I want that web browser application (not native application) to run on every mobile phone's web browser and my questions are

- How I am going to adjust layout for different screen resolution? How can I achieve cross-platform compatibility make it look ok on every device. Do I need to do have a CSS file and have layouts for different resolutions.
- If I need to have layouts, is there any cross platform mobile web browser application developing tool that gets html5 files and generates modified htlm5 files with layouts for different resolutions?

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To automatically adapt the screen resolution, you can use 3rd party framwork such as http://jquerymobile.com , http://jqtouch.com , and http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/ . But the widest cross browser compatibility is jQueryMobile, take a look at http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/
2. I don`t really know about the tools what you want. But so far I developed by using framework, so cross browser compatibilty will be less painful. I write the code by using 'commonly used IDE' such as Aptana, and Eclipse with JSDT.
3. I don`t think you can access phone hardware feature by using pure javascript. For GPS, I`ve never tried to use HTML5 geolocation API on mobile web apps. But there is 3rd party bridging tools to make your HTML5 web apps to have access on hardware device and ported as native apps, it is http://phonegap.com .

Hope this help you, Correct me if I`m wrong :D

Comment: Thanks a lot answering my questions. I read that you can access some phone hardware feature like uploading an image from the device camera. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/ example 5.1 and can use GPS features as well.

What I need to know is if I need to do modification on the html5 file for different resolutions or there is no need for modification and just leave it as it is.